# How to export graph in different formats in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

As a follow-up to this post: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cytoscape-discuss/GV2vr4d4EQI

I was wondering if there is any documentation/example on how we can use cytoscape.js' export functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, we only support JSON as an input/output graph file format.  You can also export the graph as a PNG image with `cy.png()`.

Conversion to and from formats like XGMML will have to be a separate component/library.

Comment: how about at least exporting to JSON?  is there a way to export the entire graph as JSON?

Comment: You can use ele.json() or cy.json()